# onclick Event (select field) on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, mobile

i have a select field and use onclick event to call a JS function.

```
<select size="6" name="Network" id ="Network" style="width: 255px;" onclick="javascript: Ajax_Show_Info();" onselect="javascript: Ajax_Show_WiFiInfo();" />
  <option value="1"> Option 1</option>
  <option value="1"> Option 2</option>
  <option value="1"> Option 3</option>
</select>
```

On PC everything works fine. On my mobile phone Ajax_Show_Info() is called when I select the next option. For example wehn I click option 1, nothing happens, when I click on option 2 the function Ajax_Show_Info() is called but for option 2 etc.

Is there an event which would work on mobile device? Onselect doens't also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `onchange` event? It will call the function each time the option value gets changed. Also notice that you have kept values for all options same.

```
<select size="6" name="Network" id ="Network" style="width: 255px;" onchange="Ajax_Show_Info();">
  <option value="1"> Option 1</option>
  <option value="2"> Option 2</option>
  <option value="3"> Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, but also without effort. Oprions in my example above are just samples. Real values are filled by an ajax script.

Comment: @af_bln Maybe you should post your original script , since it could contain some errors.

Comment: Solved, it was my fault, since i have overwritten always the onchange event withing changing the outerHTML of select field by ajax. The change was containing the onklick event.

Comment: @af_bln Cool , you should close this question by selecting appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use other events?
For example: oninput?
Here is the complete events list for select object:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Comment: ´: The same, the function is called with the older option value.